# Is it possible to obtain a QModelIndex from col and row

Tags: c++, qt

If I have a QStandardItemModel and have the row and column to a cell. I wanted to know if it is possible to obtain a QModelIndex from a row and col value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with table, you can use [QStandardItemModel::index](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#index). Parent is QModelIndex by default in the table.

```
model->index(row, col);
```